# Don't we need to unit test what is returned by array_filter?

Tags: php, unit-testing

There is a function:

```
public filter($array)
{
   return array_filter(function($item) {
       return $item['a'] = 1 || $item['b'] = 2;
   }, $array);
}
```

My colleague said that function like this does not need tests. What are you going to test - php array_filter function?

But we can still introduce a bug by setting wrong filtering condition. So I do not understand why this does not need to be tested?

Comment: This could be classed as opinion based - but what if someone removed array_filter and hand coded it, of course the function needs testing.

Comment: even if it is opinion based, then my opinion is not wrong, and that would be good to know. But from what I read in Robert Martin book - almost everything should be tested, so since this is easy to test, by this book it means it should be tested.

Comment: I usually go on the principle of 'if someone can screw it up, they will' so test anything that someone could change.